# Register a Generic Type with Autofac, using Constructor selection and named-Types

Tags: c#, generics, inversion-of-control, autofac, registration

My "Worker-Classes" require a registration with a predefined constructor, because the contructor injection needs to resolve named parameters.

In past I've registered this Worker-Types in that way:

```
builder.Register<SomeWorker>(
 ctx => new SomeWorker(
    ctx.ResolveNamed<ICentralLogger>("GlobalLog"),
    ctx.ResolveNamed<ICentralLogger>("WorkerLog"),
    ctx.Resolve<IStorageProvider>(),
    ctx.Resolve<IConfigProvider>())
)
.As<IWorker>()
.Named<IWorker>("SomeWorker");
```

That's worked fine so far.

Now I had to extend the IWorker interface and the implementations (like SomeWorker) with 3 generic type annotations

```
interface IWorker<T1,T2,T2> 
{}

class SomeWorker<T1,T2,T2> : IWorker<T1,T2,T2>
{}
```

I'm struggling to find the right registration syntax, that fits with the named constructor injection arguments.

For testing I tried a registration without constructor selection, but the workers weren't registered in the container ...:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(SomeWorker<,,>)
    .As(typeof(IWorker<,,>))
    .Named("SomeWorker", typeof(IWorker<,,>));
```

Finally I need help to find a generic registration like this (not working pseudo-code):

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(SomeWorker<,,>),
ctx => new SomeWorker(
    ctx.ResolveNamed<ICentralLogger>("GlobalLog"),
    ctx.ResolveNamed<ICentralLogger>("WorkerLog"),
    ctx.Resolve<IStorageProvider>(),
    ctx.Resolve<IConfigProvider>())
)
.As(typeof(IWorker<,,>))
.Named("SomeWorker", typeof(IWorker<,,>));
```

Edit:

**Sample Interface and Sample IWorker Implementation:**
I've around 5 IWorker Implementations, 8 BaseJob descendants, 8 result types (IJobResult implementations) and 3 StorageProviders.

```
public interface IWorker<TJ, TJR, TS> : IDisposable
    where TJR : IJobResult<TJ, TS>
    where TJ : BaseJob
    where TS : IStorageProvider
{
    IWorker<TJ, TJR, TS> CreateJob( .... );
    IWorker<TJ, TJR, TS> Validate( .... );
    TJR RunJob();
    Task<TJR> RunJobAsync();
}   

public class SomeWorker<TJ, TJR, TS> : IWorker<TJ, TJR, TS>, IDisposable
    where TJR : IJobResult<TJ, TS>
    where TJ : SomeJob
    where TS : IStorageProvider
{

    public SomeWorker(ICentralLogger globalLog, ICentralLogger workerLog, LocalFileSystemStorageProvider storageProvider, IConfigProvider configProvider)
    {
        m_GlobalLog = globalLog;
        m_WorkerLog = workerLog;
        ...
        InitializeWorker(configProvider.GetWorkerConfig((typeof(this).GetName.Name));
    }

    #region IWorker
     // ...
    #endregion

    #region IDisposable
    public Dispose()
    {}
    #endregion      
}
```

Comment: Your question title should [probably not have tags in it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) - you should rephrase to remove the explicit "C#" and "Autofac" separation/tag in the title.

Comment: Open generics like this are sort of tough because you need to _somehow_ not only provide the _type arguments_ but also the _constructor arguments_. Can you provide the constructor for the open generic type `SomeWorker<T1, T2, T3>`?

Comment: I've changed the title and added the IWorker Interface and a sample implementation.